# How to re-enable developer options

Tags: android, google-pixel

I've turned off the developer options from Settings in a Google Pixel 3a by turning off the general switch in the Developer Options section.

From this point onwards, no developer mode section is shown in the Advanced Settings and the default activation (tappiing 7 times over the build version) doesn't work anymore.

Any help please?

Answer (score -1):

Tapping on build number will re-enable developer options in System under Settings.